# Google cloud messaging on GoogleTV

Tags: android, google-tv

I want to receive real time push notifications from my Tornado webserver to my GoogleTV over the internet.I understand Google Cloud messaging is one option I have to send notifications to android devices.
Just want to confirm that i wont have any problem with GCM on GoogleTV before i start with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work.  There should be no problem.

** Actually at the time I wrote this it was expected to work.  However, GSF isn't on the current version of Google TV.  We hope to have the problem fixed for the JB release. **